# TDD on a configuration tool touching database

Tags: c#, tdd

I am working on writing a tool which 
- sets up a connection to Sql and runs a series of stored procedures 
- Hits the file system to verify and also delete files
- Talks to other subsystems through exposed APIs

I am new to the concept of TDD but have been doing a lot of reading on it. I wanted apply TDD for this development but I am stuck. There are a lot of interactions with external systems which need to be mocked/stubbed or faked. What I am finding difficult is the proper approach to take in doing this in TDD.. here is a sample of what I would like accomplished.

```
public class MyConfigurator
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        CheckSystemIsLicenced(); // will throw if its not licenced. Makes call to a library owned by company

        CleanUpFiles(); // clean up several directories

        CheckConnectionToSql(); //ensure connection to sql can be made

        ConfigureSystemToolsOnDatabase(); //runs a set of stored procedure. Range of checks are also implemented and will throw if something goes wrong.
    }
}
```

After this I have another class which cleans up the system if things have gone wrong. For the purpose of this question, its not that relevant but it essentially will just clear certain tables and fix up database so that the tool can run again from scratch to do its configuration tasks.

It almost appears to be here that when using TDD the only tests I end up having are things like (assuming I am using FakeItEasy)

```
A.CallTo(()=>fakeLicenceChecker.CheckSystemIsLicenced("lickey")).MustHaveHappened();
```

It just is a whole lot of tests which just appear to be "MustHaveHappened". Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different way to start this project using TDD? Or is this a particular scenario where perhaps TDD is not really recommended? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, if the arrangement of the unit test shows `lickey` as the input, then it is reasonable to assert that the endpoint has been called with the proper value. In more complex scenarios, the input-to-assert flow covers more subsystems so that the test itself doesn't seem as trivial. You might set up an `ID` value as input and test that down the line you are outputting a value for an object that is deterministically related to the input `ID`.

One aspect of TDD is that the code changes while the tests do not - except for functionally equivalent refactoring. So your first tests would naturally arrange and assert data at the outermost endpoints. You would start with a test that writes a real file to the filesystem, calls your code, and then checks to see that the file is deleted as expected. Of course, the file system is a messy workspace for portable testing, so you might decide early on to abstract the file system by one step. Ditto with the database by using EF and mocking your DbContext or by using a mocked repository pattern. These abstractions can be pre-TDD application architecture decisions.

Something I do frequently is to use utility code that starts with an `IFileSystem` interface that declares methods that mimic a lot of what is available in System.IO.File. In production I use an implementation of `IFileSystem` that just passes through to `File.XXX()` methods. Then you can mock up and verify the interface instead of trying to setup and cleanup real files.

Comment: Thanks Keith for clearing it up. Appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

In this particular method the only thing you can test is that the methods were called. It's ok to do what you are doing by asserting the mock classes. It's up to you to determine if this particular test is valuable or not. TDD assumes tests for everything, but I find it to be more practical to focus your testing on scenarios where it adds value. Hard for others to make that determination, but you should trust yourself to make the call in each specific scenario.

Comment: Not to be a TDD-nazi, but really TDD doesn't assume tests for everything. There are tests for everything because the tests drive the code. If there is no test, there is no reason to write the code in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think integration tests would add the most bang for buck. Use the real DB and FileSystem.

If you have complex logic in the tool, then you may want to restructure the tool design to abstract out the DB and fileSystem and write the unit tests with mocks. From the code snippet you posted, it looks like a simple script to me.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think your right that this can be done in a simple script. But there are other complexions which I have not mentioned to keep the example clear.